# AWS Cloudwatch Agent config for sysmin log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I try to collect Sysmon logfiles with AWS CloudWatchAgent.

How do I need to specify the event_name section in the config?

I tried these

```
"event_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon"
```

then (most obvious)

```
"event_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational"
```

and this

```
"event_name": "Sysmon"
```

But nothing works ...

Thanks

Robert

Answer (score 1):

"event_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational"

is correct.